# Does NEAR (proximity) searching work with the CONTAINS (full-text) predicate on SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008, full-text-search

If I search on

```
 WHERE CONTAINS (column_name, 'fox NEAR chicken')
```

the document is still returned, even if the words fox and chicken are hundreds or thousands of words apart in column_name.

I would have assumed that only documents where those words are within 50 (or so) words of each other would have been returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the book *Pro Full-Text Search in SQL Server 2008*:

> ... the NEAR operator is basically
>   useless with the iFTS CONTAINS and
>   FREETEXT predicates (it's no
>   difference from using the AND
>   operator). To get a true proximity
>   search, you need to use CONTAINSTABLE
>   or FREETEXTTABLE and restrict the
>   results with the WHERE clause. Your
>   WHERE clause predicate should specify
>   that the RANK column returned by the
>   iFTS function needs to be greater than
>   0...